# nhibernate NamedQuery from criteriaQuery -->  help needed

Tags: nhibernate, hql, nhibernate-criteria, named-query, any

I am trying to convert a working criteria query into a named query, and not getting the syntax right. The hql version apparently wants both the type and id params specified.

The query is over a class mapped with ANY (below also)

Can someone give me a hand getting the syntax right?

Cheers,
Berryl

## WORKING criteria query

```
    result = _session
        .CreateCriteria<Allocation>()
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq(propName_Resource, resource))
        .Add(Restrictions.Between(propName_StartTime, (DateTime)searchRange.Start, (DateTime)searchRange.End))
        .AddOrder(Order.Asc(propName_StartTime))
        .List<Allocation>();

                produces
SELECT this_.AllocationId as Allocati1_2_0_, this_.ResourceType as Resource2_2_0_, this_.ResourceId as ResourceId2_0_, this_.ActivityType as Activity4_2_0_, 
        this_.ActivityId as ActivityId2_0_, this_.StartTime as StartTime2_0_, this_.EndTime as EndTime2_0_, this_.PostingTime as PostingT8_2_0_ 
FROM Allocations this_ 
WHERE this_.ResourceType = @p0 and this_.ResourceId = @p1 and this_.StartTime between @p2 and @p3 ORDER BY this_.StartTime asc;@p0 = 'EMPLOYEE' [Type: String (0)], @p1 = 98304 [Type: Int32 (0)], @p2 = 3/14/2011 12:00:00 AM [Type: DateTime (0)], @p3 = 3/20/2011 11:59:59 PM [Type: DateTime (0)] 2011-03-14 Mon - 2011-03-20 Sun
```

## The ANY Mapping (which WORKS!)

```
<any name="Resource" cascade="all" id-type="System.Int32" meta-type="System.String"
     >
  <meta-value value="EMPLOYEE" class="Employee, ..." />
  <meta-value value="Facility" class="Facility, ..." />

  <column name="ResourceType"/>
  <column name="ResourceId"/>
</any>
```

## NAMED QUERY SO FAR (NOT working)

I *think* this is the hql syntax but error message says a param is missing

```
....
          select a 
          from Allocation a 
          where a.Resource = :resource 
            and a.TimeRange.StartTime between :periodStart and :periodEnd
          order by a.TimeRange.StartTime
....

        return _session.GetNamedQuery("FetchByResourceForDateRange")
            .SetEntity("resource", resource)
            .SetDateTime("periodStart", searchRange.Start)
            .SetDateTime("periodEnd", searchRange.End)
            .List<Allocation>();

NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException : could not execute query
[ select allocation0_.AllocationId as Allocati1_2_, allocation0_.ResourceType as   Resource2_2_, allocation0_.ResourceId as ResourceId2_, allocation0_.ActivityType as Activity4_2_, allocation0_.ActivityId as ActivityId2_, allocation0_.StartTime as StartTime2_, allocation0_.EndTime as EndTime2_, allocation0_.PostingTime as PostingT8_2_ from Allocations allocation0_ where allocation0_.ResourceType=@p0 and allocation0_.ResourceId=@p1 and (allocation0_.StartTime between @p2 and @p3) order by allocation0_.StartTime ]
  Name:resource - Value:George Washington 000001  Name:periodStart - Value:3/14/2011 12:00:00 AM  Name:periodEnd - Value:3/20/2011 11:59:59 PM
[SQL: select ... 
    from Allocations allocation0_ 
where allocation0_.ResourceType=@p0 and allocation0_.ResourceId=@p1 and (allocation0_.StartTime between @p2 and @p3) 
order by allocation0_.StartTime]

 ----> System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException : SQLite error
Insufficient parameters supplied to the command
```

## UPDATE

this combination executes but gives the wrong answer. can't tell if it is closer or further from what I need yet

```
          select a 
          from Allocation a 
          where a.Resource.class = :class and a.Resource.id = :id 
            and a.TimeRange.StartTime between :periodStart and :periodEnd
          order by a.TimeRange.StartTime

        return _session.GetNamedQuery("FetchByResourceForDateRange")
            .SetString("class", typeof(Resource).FullName)
            .SetInt32("id", resource.Id)
            .SetDateTime("periodStart", searchRange.Start)
            .SetDateTime("periodEnd", searchRange.End)
            .List<Allocation>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, per Fabio Maulo, lead dev on NHib:

"You have to use your meta-data values not the typeof(entity).FullName"

So in my case the following made the last hql I had work:

```
return _session.GetNamedQuery("FetchByResourceForDateRange")
        .SetString("class", "EMPLOYEE")
        .SetInt32("id", resource.Id)
        .SetDateTime("periodStart", searchRange.Start)
        .SetDateTime("periodEnd", searchRange.End)
        .List<Allocation>();
```

A bit uglier than I would have hoped but I'll take it :--)

HTH,
Berryl